# How to import .xsd or .wsdl files in Python 3.2

Tags: python, import, xsd, wsdl, python-3.2

I am new to Python and currently am doing some translations from 2.7 to 3.2 after running 2to3 tool. One of the things that it couldn't fix is importing .xsd or .wsdl files. In 2.7
stuff like `import content` , where content is .xsd file in our directory seemed to work fine, but 3.2 cannot resolve this import. Does anybody know how can I do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're using a code generator on your `.xsd` and `.wsdl` files, correct?

Otherwise, I am confused what you mean when you say you cannot import a `.xsd` file; 
I don't think the Python import toolchain lets you do this without a new importer 
written specific for SOAP clients.

I recently had to communicate with a SOAP service and settled on [suds](https://fedorahosted.org/suds/).

The `Client` object in suds takes in a url to a wsdl file (I had to modify the url to use `file://` in order to specify a local .wsdl file)

```
from suds.client import Client

a = Client(<url_to_wsdl_file>)
a.service.Method()
```

Hope this helps!  I'm not sure if suds is Python 3 compliant, and a quick search didn't yield any useful information.

Answer (score 1):

*Update for 2018:*

---

Please use [python-zeep](https://github.com/mvantellingen/python-zeep) instead of `suds`.  It's well supported and actively developed.  Suds is not.  It's also *much* faster than suds

---

Sample, taken from the [docs](http://docs.python-zeep.org/en/master/):

```
client = Client('http://www.webservicex.net/ConvertSpeed.asmx?WSDL')
result = client.service.ConvertSpeed(
    100, 'kilometersPerhour', 'milesPerhour')
```